# Model form not being saved

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, modelform

I have created a modelform and would like to save the data when a user enters values in the template and clicks submit.

I have tried following a [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qwE9TFNub84) to guide me. However, the form doesn't seem to be saving nor am I being redirected to the template I specified

This is what I have on views.py

```
class PaymentView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'classroom/teachers/app-student-dashboard.html'

    def get(self, request):
        paymentform = MentorPaymentForm()
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'paymentform':paymentform})

    def post(self, request):
        paymentform = MentorPaymentForm(request.POST)
        if paymentform.is_valid:
            payment = paymentform.save(commit=False)
            payment.user = request.user
            payment.save()
            address = paymentform.cleaned_data['address']
            country = paymentform.cleaned_data['country']
            invoice_name = paymentform.cleaned_data['invoice_name']
            account_num = paymentform.cleaned_data['account_num']
            bank_name = paymentform.cleaned_data['bank_name']
            branch_code = paymentform.cleaned_data['branch_code']
            paymentform = MentorPaymentForm()
            return redirect('teachers:app-instructor-dashboard')

        args = {'paymentform': paymentform, 'address': address,
                'country': country, 'invoice_name': invoice_name,
                'account_num': account_num, 'bank_name': bank_name,
                'branch_code': branch_code}
        return render(request, self.template_name, args)
```

forms.py

```
class MentorPaymentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Mentor
        fields = ('address', 'country', 'invoice_name', 'account_num', 'bank_name', 'branch_code')
```

models.py:

```
class Mentor(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='mentor')
    COUNTRIES = (
        ('SA', 'South Africa'),
        ('NG', 'Nigeria'),
        ('KE', 'Kenya'),
        ('OT', 'Other')
    )
    address = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=30, choices=COUNTRIES)
    invoice_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False, blank=False)
    account_num = models.IntegerField(default=1234)
    bank_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False)
    branch_code = models.IntegerField(default=1234)
```

and my template:

```
<form id="edit-payment-details", method="post",enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-horizontal">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="name" class="col-md-2 control-label">Name on Invoice</label>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                          <div class="form-control-material">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control used" id="name" value="{{ paymentform.invoice_name }}">
                              {{ paymentform.invoice_name }}
                            <label for="invoice_name"></label>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="address" class="col-md-2 control-label">Address</label>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                          <div class="form-control-material">
                            <textarea class="form-control used" id="address"> </textarea>
                              {{ paymentform.address }}
                            <label for="address">Address</label>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="country" class="col-md-2 control-label">Country</label>
...
                          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success paper-shadow relative" data-z="0.5" data-hover-z="1" data-animated>Update Billing</button>
```

I have noticed that I have one unapplied migration, however when I try and run migrate I get the error message:

```
Apply all migrations: admin, auth, classroom, contenttypes, sessions
Running migrations:
  Applying classroom.0014_auto_20200120_1042...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 383, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
sqlite3.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: new__classroom_mentor.id
```

**UPDATE**

To try and resolve the error message that appeared when I ran migrate. I tried deleting all migrations then running makemigrations and migrate again. I am no longer getting the error Unique constraint failed error. However I am still not able to save the form's data to my database

```
find . -path "*/migr
ations/*.py" -not -name "__init__.py" -delete
```

Comment: Are you sure that you don have any inconsistencies in the database regarding the new__classroom_mentor.id field?
I think you should resolve that first and then work on your model form

Comment: @Batman none that I am aware of

Comment: paymentform.is_valid should be called as method not attribute: paymentform.is_valid()

Answer (score 0):

As [@HelenShy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11449888/helenshy) mentioned. You must use

```
if paymentform.is_valid():
```

instead of

```
if paymentform.is_valid:
```

Since it is a method and not an attribute